# A Different SQL Server for Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, architecture, topology

Is it possible to configure SharePoint to use one SQL Server setup with Database Engine Services for configurations and content databases and another SQL Server setup with SharePoint Reporting Services and Add-in for SharePoint Products for reporting?

Our DBA says that for security reasons they won't install Reporting Services and Database Engine Services on the same SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is absolutely possible to configure the reporting services from a different dedicated SQL server running SSRS.  the below are main points which explains what is needed:

1. Use SharePoint Central Administration to configure report server integration. Configuration settings include specifying a single report server URL, setting an authentication type on requests directed to the report server, granting database access permissions to the Report Server service account.
2. Set report server defaults that enable logging, ad hoc reporting, and limits for report history and time-out values.

I would suggest to refer the following tech net article as well

[Reference Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Bb326356(v=SQL.105).aspx)

Also, if you want to build a more robust sharepoint farm with dedicated sharepoint server with SSRS then you may consider following the below link :

[Reference Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479774.aspx)

Comment: Thank you kesava this is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!